# Web API Routes conflicting with each other

Tags: c#, api, routes

Apologies if this has been asked before, I probably haven't been searching well enough.

I'm using attribute routing. Basically I have
`[Route("api/studies")]` that gives me a list of type study.
`[Route("api/studies/{id}/{detail?}")]` That gives me a single study. This has an optional parameter, detail, that specifies the level of detail.
`[Route("api/studies/{id}/subjects")]` That gives me a list of subjects in a study.

Problem is, when I test the subjects route, it calls `/api/studies/{id}/{detail?}` and passes "subjects" in as the detail parameter. I totally understand why, I'm just curious if there is a way to prevent it.

Comment: Assign the `{detail?}` one a higher [order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routeattribute.order?view=aspnetcore-3.1)?

Comment: I figured it out below, although yeah right after posting the question I had discovered the order attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I figured it out. First of all, I hadn't assigned them orders. I did that, still didn't work. BUT... wasn't entirely honest with my post, I left out some stuff that I didn't think was relevant. The subjects had a bunch of optional parameters that were integers, and I thought that putting them in like this was ok:
`public List<Subject> Subjects(long id, int? limit, int? offset)`

Apparently that isn't good enough. Needed to be:
`public List<Subject> Subjects(long id, int? limit = null, int? offset = null)`

Didn't know I had to assign them as null!